# Why does my prime number algorithm need a break in the for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, primes, break

I wrote an algorithm that populates a list with the first 1000 primes.

When I run it like this, it populates the list with some numbers that aren't prime.

```
def is_prime():
    primes = [2]
    a = 0
    x = 3
    while a < 999:
        for i in range(2, x):
            if (x % i) == 0:
                x += 2
                break
        else:
            primes.append(x)
            a += 1
            x += 2
    return primes


print is_prime()
```

Comment: Please properly indent your code.

Comment: and perhaps not post exactly same code?

Comment: What are the values you weren't expecting?

Comment: It looks fine to me...

Answer (score 2):

> [Why does this] need a break in the for loop?

Let me quote [this tutorial you might want to look at](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html):

> Loop statements may have an **else** clause; it is executed when the loop terminates through **exhaustion** of the list (with for) [...], but *not* when the loop is terminated by a **break** statement.

This means that in your `while`-loop,

```
 primes.append(x)
 a += 1
 x += 2
```

is only executed if the `for`-loop has iterated over all `i in range(2, x)` and never once encountered `break`. (This means, that there was no divisor of x found)

*Without* the `break`statement the code above would be executed in *every iteration* of the `while`-loop. Therefore, without the `break` statement you just add `2` to `x` every time you find a divisor of x and claim that x is prime as soon as you reach the end of `range(2, x)` (note that in the range expression it's the original `x` before you started adding `2`). This seems to work for small numbers but is not the same as checking if x has any divisors.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm seems to work.

For example, compare to a more [standard approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n-in-python):

```
def rwh_primes(n):
    """ Returns  a list of primes < n """
    sieve = [True] * n
    for i in xrange(3,int(n**0.5)+1,2):
        if sieve[i]:
            sieve[i*i::2*i]=[False]*((n-i*i-1)/(2*i)+1)
    return [2] + [i for i in xrange(3,n,2) if sieve[i]]

p0 = is_prime()  # OP's code
p1 = rwh_primes(7920)

print p0==p1   # prints True, so the lists are equal
```